# Kubernetes Ingress - Load balancer traffic split

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have a kubernetes ingress of class `nginx` and two load balancers. Running on GKE v1.17.

Sample ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    # Enable client certificate authentication
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    # Create the secret containing the trusted ca certificates
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "production/client-cert-secret"
    # Specify the verification depth in the client certificates chain
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    # Automatically redirect http to https
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    # Use regex in paths
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    # Allow larger request body
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 30m
    # For notifications we add the proxy headers
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |  
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - my-domain.com
      secretName: my-tls-certificate
  rules:
  - host: my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: load-balancer-1
          servicePort: 443
```

I wish to split the traffic reached to the ingress between the two load balancers.
For example:

`load-balancer-1` will receive 90% of the traffic

`load-balancer-2` will receive 10% of the traffic

**How can I do that with kubernetes ingress?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nginx ingress controller supports canary deployments through the [Canary Annotations](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#canary)

> In some cases, you may want to "canary" a new set of changes by
> sending a small number of requests to a different service than the
> production service. The canary annotation enables the Ingress spec to
> act as an alternative service for requests to route to depending on
> the rules applied. The following annotations to configure canary can
> be enabled after `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"` is set:
>
> - `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight`: The integer based (0 - 100)
>   percent of random requests that should be routed to the service
>   specified in the canary Ingress. A weight of 0 implies that no
>   requests will be sent to the service in the Canary ingress by this
>   canary rule. A weight of 100 means implies all requests will be sent
>   to the alternative service specified in the Ingress.
>
> Note that when you mark an ingress as canary, then all the other
> non-canary annotations will be ignored (inherited from the
> corresponding main ingress) except
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balance and
> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-hash-by.
>
> **Known Limitations**
>
> Currently a maximum of one canary ingress can be applied per Ingress
> rule.

In other words, you can introduce a new Ingress Object `my-ingress-canary` where you set the annotations

- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"` (Tells Nginx Ingress to mark this one as “Canary” and associate this ingress with the main ingress by matching host and path.
- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: "10"` (Route ten percent traffic to load-balancer-2)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress-canary
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/canary-weight: "10"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: load-balancer-2
          servicePort: 443
```

Comment: Really good answer, I dont see why they dont unify how ingresses implement of canary releases.Traefik has way better conf :
....
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-weights: |
      lb-1: 50%
      lb-2: 50%
spec:
  rules:
  - host: my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: lb-1
          servicePort: 443
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: lb-2
          servicePort: 443

Comment: Yeah, there is a lot of stuff that can be done with a L7 component that is not in the native specs of ingress. Sticky sessions and header based routing are two other examples. I guess they want to keep the spec clean and generic, but when something as central as canary deployments are not possible to spec natively people lock themselves into products like nginx och Traeffic anyway